# Load images with select list in Div tag

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to load picture in div tag with select list, when I click on Picture 1, Picture 1 to load. When I click on Picture 2, Picture 2 to load... And, when, for example, Picture 1 is loaded and when press Next button  Picture 2 to load...I tried in many ways but I failed.

```
<select id="mypicture" class="dropdown">
<option value="">Choose picture...</option>
<option value="1">Picture 1</option>
<option value="2">Picture 2</option>
<option value="3">Picture 3</option>
<option value="4">Picture 4</option>          
       </select>
```

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/Wdw4z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the actual image display in your code.

What you need to do, is after you reconfigure all the buttons in your change event handler, you need to display an image.

```
$('div').html('<img src="'+imgUrl+'">');
```

and you need to set the imgUrl depending on the value of the select, or have the url on the option element so you can retrieve it like so:

```
<option value="1" data-imgurl="imgs/img1.jpg">
```

I have updated your fiddle with another solution http://jsfiddle.net/Wdw4z/1/

Comment: Rodik,that's it, thank's very much. It works perfectly for one select list, but, with two lists does not work. For example, I have two lists _Choose dog picture..._ and _Choose cat picture..._ _Choose dog picture..._ works but _Choose cat picture..._ does not work. In _Choose cat picture..._ I set for Picture 1 _value="101"_ and _img101.jpg_ but does not work. Can you help me, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/UEMCy/) is my code with two list.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this:

**Option 1**

Add a `img` tag to your div. for every change to your dropdown, you can change the `src` of the img tag accordingly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MfPyU/

**Option 2**

This is my preference, you can create a new img tag dynamically using JS. The benefit of this in my opinion is you can add an `onload` event listener to the image and display text such as 'loading' while the image loads.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QW4Sp/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `img` and append it to the `div`.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pictures = ["https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQYN2T3dktBEDIuwIuosj8ulzlwGod-KabDTy2vBFC-Kht_u4ep","https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgBLpqp92lc7JQiNszqO_ZP52OymeqShqxqcrlUDcae9UaTTLtfQ", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS99xzsoRm3g0nckrH-SjfgSe8zgeYSCgc23IqtbtocZo3sjZN2gA", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBLBxc5mMj9WbV9ghIyfpmOfVdt0qyIe21f8HBlqwvVoGgCxQucA"];
    $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });

    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        var value = $('.dropdown').val();
        if (value== 0) {
          $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
        } else if (value == 1) {

          $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
        } else if (value == 4) {
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true }); 
        } else {
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
          $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: false });
        }

        //Emptys picture div and appends image
        $("#picture").empty();
        $("#picture").append($("<img/>",{src: pictures[value-1]}));
    });
$(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });

});
$("#next").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mypicture > option:selected').next('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mypicture > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  $('.dropdown').trigger('change');      
  }
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mypicture > option:selected').prev('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
    $('#mypicture > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
  $('.dropdown').trigger('change');        
  }  
});
```

**HTML**

```
     <select id="mypicture" class="dropdown">
<option value="">Choose picture...</option>
<option value="1">Picture 1</option>
<option value="2">Picture 2</option>
<option value="3">Picture 3</option>
<option value="4">Picture 4</option>          
       </select>
<hr>
<button id="prev" class="prevbutton">Previous</button>
<button id="next" class="nextbutton">Next</button>
 <hr>
<div id="picture">
</div>
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Wdw4z/3/